# Gatsby conditional className based on frontmatter

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I'm trying to add a className of `split` to my header, based on the page template as defined in the frontmatter of a page. I've got a page template called `split` and want the header to have that class on pages that are utilizing the template. Here are my templates:

**layout.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'
import '../css/main.scss'

import favicon from './favicon.png'

const Layout = ({ children, frontmatter }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query PageInfoQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            footer
          }
        }
        markdownRemark {
          frontmatter {
            template
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <Helmet
          title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
          meta={[
            { name: 'description', content: 'Sample' },
            { name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something' },
          ]}
          link={[
            {
              rel: 'shortcut icon',
              type: 'image/png',
              href: `${favicon}`,
            },
          ]}
        >
          <html lang="en" />
        </Helmet>
        <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} frontmatter={data.markdownRemark.frontmatter}/>
        {children}
        <Footer footer={data.site.siteMetadata.footer} />
      </>
    )}
  />
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

**header.js**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import Navbar from './navbar' 

const Header = ({ siteTitle, frontmatter }) => (
  <header className={ frontmatter.template === 'split' ? 'header split' : 'header' }>
    <section className="navigation">
      <Navbar siteTitle={siteTitle} />
    </section>
  </header>

)

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: '',
}

export default Header
```

I know that I've got the `data.markdownRemark.frontmatter` working correctly, as in my template `split.js` I'm able to display the template name dynamically in the `hero` element, using `{post.frontmatter.template}`. In the interest of being thorough I'll include that as well.

**split.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import Layout from '../components/layout'

// import blocks
import Feature from '../components/blocks/feature'
import Hero from '../components/blocks/hero'

class BlocksTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const post = this.props.data.markdownRemark
    const siteTitle = this.props.data.site.siteMetadata.title
    const siteDescription = post.excerpt
    const heroImage = post.frontmatter.hero_image.childImageSharp.fixed.src

    return (
      <Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
        <Helmet
          htmlAttribute={{ lang: 'en' }}
          meta={[{ name: 'description', content: siteDescription }]}
          title={`${post.frontmatter.title} • ${siteTitle}`}
        />
        <section className="hero" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${heroImage})` }}>
          <h4 className="name">
            <Link to="/">
              {this.props.siteTitle}
              {post.frontmatter.template}
            </Link>
          </h4>
        </section>
        {post.frontmatter.blocks.map(block => {
          switch (block.component) {
            case 'feature':
              return <Feature block={block} />
            case 'hero':
              return <Hero block={block} />
            default:
              return ''
          }
        })}
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default BlocksTemplate

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query SplitPageBySlug($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      id
      excerpt
      html
      frontmatter {
        template
        title
        hero_image {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 1500) {
              src
            }
          }
        }
        blocks {
          component
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              fixed(width: 1500) {
                src
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Here is the header markup that is being rendered; in essence the `split` class is never being added.

```
<header class="header">
  <section class="navigation">
    <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
      <div class="branding">
        <a href="/"><h6 class="name">Jesse Winton</h6></a>
      </div>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a aria-current="page" class="" href="/about-the-demo">What is this?</a>
      <a href="/about-the-ssg">About Gatsby</a>
      <a href="/posts">Blog</a>
    </nav>
  </section>
</header>
```

I'm fairly new to Gatsby, so any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @coreyward updated my question to provide more clarity. Thank you!

Comment: Is it simply a matter of `frontmatter.template` never being `"split"` in `Header`?

Comment: Yes, it’s not actually displaying the className on the pages that utilize the split template.

Comment: I don't see `{post.frontmatter.template}` in `hero` ...  `  <Link to="/">
              {this.props.siteTitle}
              {post.frontmatter.template}
            </Link>` - only `siteTitle` rendered ?

Comment: @xadm that’s correct, but I’m needing to add a class to the `header` depending on the page template that’s being used. How can I create a conditional to do that?

Comment: " I'm able to display the template name dynamically in the hero element, using {post.frontmatter.template}" - I don't see it's true

Answer (score 0):

In `layout.js`, you are passing `frontmatter={data.markdownRemark.frontmatter}` to the header from the query above it in layout.js. This is a `staticQuery` which will always return the same data.

I see you are querying for the correct data in the `pageQuery` in split.js, but this data is not passed along to the layout in split.js:

```
<Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
```

One way to fix this is to pass the template name to the layout props, just like you are already doing with location and title attributes.

Another way would be using the [gatsby-plugin-layout](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/) plugin which return the old behavior from V1 Gatsby for the Layout component, adding a layout wrapper to every component. Then you could the `pageContext` to the split component directly.

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you help me clarify how to pass the data to the header and add the class based on the template? Like I said, I’m fairly new to Gatsby and React, so any help would be great!